# Name an array with a preexisting string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, set

I have a for loop that creates a string array with set number of indexes and fills it with strings. Im going to have a second for loop that makes more arrays and names these arrays as the strings from my previous array. It wont take the string as the name and so im stuck. Any suggestions to get around this?

Im doing this in C#.

Thank You

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class World : MonoBehaviour {

    public int WorldSize;
    const int q = 1000;
    const int w = 100;
    string [] world;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        world = new string[((WorldSize / q) * 2)];

        //int[,,] map = new string[((WorldSize / q) * 2)];

        for (int i = 0; i < ((WorldSize / q) * 2); i++){

            string h = i.ToString();

            world[i] = ("Region" + h);
            Debug.Log(world[i]);

        }



        Dictionary<string, string[]> regions = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i<world.Length; i++) {
            string h = i.ToString();
            regions.Add(world[i], new string[q/w]);
            Debug.Log(regions["Region" + h]);
        }


    }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far and let us know where it fails/does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am understanding you correctly, you have something like this:

```
string[] strArr = new string[...];
for...
{
    //something happens to strArr
}
```

Now you want to make a string array for each string element you have in your `strArr` and give that array a name which corresponds to a value in `strArr`. If that is the case, you might want to take a look at the [`Dictionary<T, K>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class:

```
string[] strArr = new string[...];
for...
{
    //something happens to strArr
}

Dictionary<string, string[]> myArrays = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
foreach(string element in strArr)
{
    myArrays.Add(element, new string[size]);
}
```

You can later access your arrays as follows: `myArrays["index"]`.

Some notes:
The code above assumes that you know the size of the arrays before hand. This might not always be possible which is why I would recommend you use the [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of the string array.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a strong typed language, and you cannot create a var with a dynamic name. 
If you need this feature, i suggest to use a dictionary. In the first field you can put the key you need, and in the sencond, the value you need

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is most probably caused by a bug: `new string[((WorldSize / q) * 2)]` creates a new array, so you don't want to do it in the loop in `Awake()`.

Try:

```
public class World : MonoBehaviour {
    public int WorldSize;
    const int q = 1000;
    const int w = 100;
    string[] world;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        //int[,,] map = new string[((WorldSize / q) * 2)];
        world = new string[((WorldSize / q) * 2)];

        for (int i = 0; i < ((WorldSize / q) * 2); i++){
            string h = i.ToString();
            world[i] = ("Region" + h);
            Debug.Log(world[i]);

        }
        Dictionary<string, string[]> regions = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        foreach(string element in world)
        {
            regions.Add(element, new string[q/w]);    
        }
        Debug.Log(regions["Region1"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i figured that out a few minutes after i posted the code. I have a new problem now. The arrays dont have names. Check linked image http://i.imgur.com/xHb16DI.png

Comment: @user3265317, my company blocks your image, so I can't see it.